# How To Insert a Row (not value by value) From Other Database with SQLite Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, row, sql-insert

I know is possible to insert rows (not by every single values) with this definition:

```
insert into table1 select * from table2
```

But what if I need to transfer rows from one database_1 table to another database_2 table? (considering that the number of columns will always match)

I would like something like this:

```
c_database_2.execute('''SELECT * FROM table 
                        WHERE date = ? 
                        AND timestamp = ?''', (a, b) 
row = c_new.fetchone() 

c_database_1.execute("INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM ?", (row))
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice they were from separate dbs.